# What is the best way to use a bottomsheet layout in combination with the MotionLayout

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet, android-motionlayout

I have an imageview in my MainActivity. When expanding my bottomsheet, then the imageview in the MainActivity should change its position and size.
Can someone lead me on the right track?

I've tried do set the motion on button click, that works. I find no way to trigger the motion by expanding the bottomsheet.

My last idea was, to fetch the sliding offset of bottomsheet and use it on the motion...but how?

Thanks, GGK

MotionScene.xml

`

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:duration="1000">
    <OnClick
        motion:target="@+id/tv_test_button"
        motion:mode="toggle"/>

    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
        motion:maxVelocity="1000"
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"/>
</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/ivTest"
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:cropToPadding="false"/>

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/ivTest"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"

        motion:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />


</ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>`
```

Answer (score 1):

found a solution to capture bottomsheet position while sliding up or down:

```
   @Override
        public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {


            View rootView = bottomSheet.getRootView();
            float yBottomSheet = bottomSheet.getY();
         }
```

That' it

GGK